# Reluctance concept

Tags: transformer, magnetics, electromagnetic, electric-machine

I would like to appeal question, where the correct answer was given as option (B) 'Cross-sectional area.' However, I believe that option (D) 'Permeance' is also inversely proportional to reluctance. Both options (B) and (D) should be considered correct answers, as they directly relate to the concept of reluctance in the context of magnetic circuits.

"The reluctance R is the opposition of the medium to the establishment and concentration of magnetic field lines. Which variable has an inversely proportional impact on the value of this quantity?

(A) Magnetomotive force
(B) Cross-sectional area
(C) Length
(D) Permeance
(E) Electric current "

I would like help writing the appeal, as it is such a simple concept and apparently the panel did not take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

> Which variable has an inversely proportional impact ...

> I believe that option (D) 'Permeance' is also inversely proportional to reluctance.

If you write the appeal it'll probably be rejected instantly. Because, permeance is the reciprocal of the reluctance, and inversely proportional and reciprocal (inverse) are not the same things so we can't say "reluctance is inversely proportional to permeance" or vice versa.

---

The question may sound tricky. The correct answer is **B** because, as I stated above, if a variable is the reciprocal of another we can NOT say "These are inversely proportional to each other".

The mathematical formula of the permeance, \$\mathcal{P}\$, is

$$
\mathcal{P} = \frac{\Phi}{MMF (=NI)}=\frac{\int B \ dA}{\int H \ dl}=\frac{B}{H}\frac{A_e}{l}=\mu \ \frac{A_e}{l}=\frac{1}{\mathcal{R}}
$$

So the reluctance, \$\mathcal{R}\$, is-

- directly proportional to MMF, \$l\$, and \$I\$. So A, C and E are wrong
- inversely proportional to \$A_e\$, so B is correct
- equal to the inverse of \$\mathcal{P}\$. This doesn't mean "inversely proportional", so D is wrong

The correct answer is B. There's no problem with the question and answer.

---

**EDIT:** Apparently, there's a need to explain why inversely proportional with a proportionality constant of 1 doesn't mean reciprocal, or vice versa.

If two variables are reciprocal of each other then the multiplication of these two equals 1, and the result is **unitless**. For example, the reciprocal of 4/7 equals to 7/4. Multiplication of these two equals to 1, with no units.

Now let's take the capacitive reactance, for example:

$$
X_C=\frac{1}{\omega C}
$$

Obviously, **the capacitive reactance is inversely proportional to the frequency** i.e. capacitive reactance decreases if frequency increases *(Though we may not be able to say the opposite due to practical limitations)*. The **proportionality constant** here is, simply, \$C\$, presumably constant.

When \$C=1\ \text{F}\$ the reactance becomes

$$
X_C\Big|_{C=1\ \text{F}}=\frac{1}{\omega}
$$

- Can we say `Angular frequency and the capacitive reactance are reciprocal of each other`? No, because s/rad is not Ohm.
- Likewise, for \$\omega = 1 \ \text{rad/s}\$, the capacitive reactance becomes \$X_C=1/C\$. Can we say `Capacitance and the capacitive reactance are reciprocal of each other`? No, because, similarly, 1/Ohms is not Farads.

The multiplication of \$X_C\$ and \$C\$ in the above example results in 1 but the unit is "s/rad" i.e. 1/(rad/s). We have to say "Capacitive reactance is inversely proportional to the capacitance", but we can **NOT** say "Capacitive reactance is the reciprocal of the capacitance".

Now for the main subject, permeance and reluctance, these are reciprocal of each other, one has a unit of H (Henry) whilst the other's is H<sup>-1</sup>. The multiplication of these two results in 1, with no units. Therefore, **permeance and the reluctance are not inversely proportional to each other**, they are just reciprocals of each other.

Comment: Why do you say that you can't say reluctance is inversely proportional to permeance? It seems to me that, by definition, it's inversely proportional with a proportionality constant of 1.

Comment: Adding, definition of inversely proportional is  x ∝ 1/y or x = k*1/y. k=1 is a valid answer to this equation. So yes, the inverse of a number is inversely proportional to that number.

Comment: @Hearth R is already 1/P, regardless of any other external conditions. R doesn't become 1/P when something else happens. What you are saying is: R was k/P with a non-zero k, and k becomes 1. But R is 1/P already. It's like saying "1/3 is inversely proportional to 3".

Comment: @InBedded16 same comment to yours.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I would consider "1/3 is inversely proportional to 3" to be a true, albeit not very useful, statement.

Comment: @Hearth when V = 1 VDC, do we say "Resistance is reciprocal of current" or "Current is inversely proportional to resistance" or "Resistance is inversely proportional to current"?

Comment: @InBedded16 same question to you as well.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Respectfully, let's not get into a back-and-forth in the comments. I looked into this for a good half hour and everything I found stated that reciprocals are inversely proportional of each other. You're welcome to provide a source otherwise to improve your answer or post this as a separate question. I for one won't respond further on this.

Comment: It would be more common to say that current is inversely proportional to resistance, but "resistance is inversely proportional to current" is still true. You can't say resistance is the reciprocal of current by the logic you give above, that there's a dimensioned proportionality constant. None of what you say invalidates anything I am claiming; I am saying that "reciprocal" is equivalent to "inversely proportional with a proportionality constant of 1". They are equal statements, and you can use either; you can't say that because "reciprocal" applies you can't say "inversely proportional".

Comment: in short, I am claiming that your last sentence is wrong. The part that states "they are reciprocals of each other" is true, but the conclusion you make in bold is exactly opposite of how I understand the term "reciprocal"; I claim that the fact that they are reciprocal in fact **necessarily implies** that they are inversely proportional.

Comment: I see it like Hearth. Reciprocity is a subgroup of inverse proportionality. @Dragnovith maybe ask about this on maths SE, to be able to write a convincing case. As the committee might otherwise keep at Rohats position

Comment: @tobalt that does makes sense to some extent but then the unitless proportionality factor becomes a problem to me. If reciprocity is a subgroup of inverse proportionality (i.e. a unitless/dimensionless prop. factor of 1) then this generalisation allows us to go one step further and say, for example, `7 is inversely proportional to 4` (because 7/4's reciprocal is 4/7) or `factorial of any natural number is proportional to zero`.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I don't see how you can make this generalization. inverse proportionality between A and B means, that if you use A*a instead, B also changes, namely to B/a. If you change 4 to 4*a, then 7 still remains 7.. They are not inversely proportional

Comment: @tobalt I'll follow your advice and ask on a math forum too. I think the two approaches you presented make sense, but I felt harmed by the organizer of the test (it's a public competition). And it would be interesting to cancel this issue because other candidates were probably harmed as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tough to answer your question because I have no idea what the situation is. Is this an entrance exam? College course final? Weekly quiz? The context matters for how you would craft this appeal.

That being said, keep it simple and humble - avoid sounding condescending. 

Dear [panel],

I was reviewing the recent test and saw that I was marked incorrect for question X. While I can see that B is a correct choice, my understanding is that D is also correct in this instance. My derivation showed that Permeance is the reciprocal of Reluctance, and reciprocals are inversely proportional to each other. (Optionally insert a quick derivation showing P=1/R, to illustrate that you've done the work and completely thought this through).

I believe I should be awarded points for correctly answering this question, as should any other student who answered D.

Edit: I'll leave my answer up but I honestly forgot which forum this was - this question is probably off topic.